# select date in tkinter without tkcalendar

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I am looking for a way to display a calendar or other date picker inside a tkinter window. I am aware of tkcalendar and it works great. However, I am looking for a way to achieve this without tkcalendar, because tkcalendar is licensed under GPLv3. I scoured the internet and all forums I found say unanimously, that a code including the words "import tkcalendar", even when not compiled, is considered a derived work and must therefore also be licensed under GPLv3. None of those threats had answers from legal experts, but I don't want to take the risk of importing anything licensed under GLP.

Can somebody suggest alternatives to tkcalendar or a suggestion on how to recreate it without copying from the source code?

Edit: I have been asked to add an explanation for what my problem with GPL is. My problem is that, as far as I understand it, a code importing tkcalendar is considered a "derived work" of tkcalendar and is therefore required to also be licensed under GPL. I don't want to license my program under GPL though, so as far as I understand it, I cannot import any GPL-licensed modules.

Comment: this looks like a standard import. what is wrong with the GLP license ?  what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Yes, it all depends on _why_ you don't want to use GLP. Are you afraid of having to publish your code? Is your code already under another license? Please [edit] your question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a calendar pretty easily by using the output of [calendar.monthcalendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls0hF.png). Just iterate over the data, creating buttons for each day.

Here's a rudimentary example. It's not complete solution, but it does show how to create the widgets and print out the day the user clicked on.

```
import tkinter as tk
import calendar

class CalendarWidget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, year, month, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        self.cal_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.cal_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        self.redraw(year, month)

    def redraw(self, year, month):
        '''Redraws the calendar for the given year and month'''

        for child in self.cal_frame.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()

        # day of the week headings
        for col, day in enumerate(("Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su")):
            label = tk.Label(self.cal_frame, text=day)
            label.grid(row=0, column=col, sticky="nsew")

        # buttons for each day
        cal = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)
        for row, week in enumerate(cal):
            for col, day in enumerate(week):
                text = "" if day == 0 else day
                state = "normal" if day > 0 else "disabled"
                cell = tk.Button(self.cal_frame, text=text, state=state, command=lambda day=day: self.set_day(day))
                cell.grid(row=row+1, column=col, sticky="nsew")

    def set_day(self, num):
        print(f"you selected day {num}")

root = tk.Tk()
c = CalendarWidget(root, year=2022, month=4, bd=2, relief="groove")
c.pack(padx=4, pady=4)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of custom widget]